# Align images (different size) and text to center in list?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to align everything to center in this example by using CSS? If not then what should I do?

As you can see the images are not the same height so it makes things even more complicated. What I want is align all images and text so they look like a line.

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cRGeD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer use span instead of li

http://jsfiddle.net/cRGeD/22/

Answer (score 0):

This could help you, I have added DIV for text and floated it to left,
then adjusted line-height 250% of li, check fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/chanduzalte/cRGeD/8/

Answer (score 0):

Edit: here I've applied the principle below to the first two items in your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cRGeD/23/.

HTML

```
<span class="icon question-icon">1234</span>
```

CSS

```
.icon{
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}

.question-icon{
  background-image: url("../path/for/images.jpg");
}
```

This way you can use a different class for a different icon, and only need to add the image path to the new class.